# How to solve the problem that SourceMap cannot be loaded in Cordova?

Tags: cordova

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for file:///android_asset/www/app/security-check/static/js/11.86c355551aa3b08f1cdf.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I have looked for a lot of solutions, but they do not meet my expectations. I mean "how to solve this loading problem", not "how to remove this warning"

Comment: I am pretty sure that the SourceMap file exists in the specified path.

Comment: Based on the error message, you should have a file located at `<project-root>/www/app/security-check/static/js/11.86c355551aa3b08f1cdf.js.map` when you build your apk.